# How to add a basic user/pass authentication for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I deployed Elasticsearch with the following the page below to my Azure Kubernetes environment.

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html
```

It works fine.

But I want to add a basic user/password authentication for Elasticsearch page. I really don't get it why it's so complicated and needs to Google it.

Then I checked this page;

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-started-enable-security.html
```

I guess I need to add "xpack.security.enabled: true" to elasticsearch.yaml file, but to where? How can I do that? I c/p and put the yaml file and it didn't worked.

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-started-enable-security.html
```

Then the documentation below mentioned about the creating passwords for built-in users, but they mentioned only manual installations, not sure how to do with Kubernetes?

`

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-started-built-in-users.html
```

`

Is there any basic documentation available for creating authentication on Elasticsearch? How can I do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by installing elasticsearch using [helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch#installing) and modifying `values.yaml`. It allows you to modify `elasticsearch.yaml`.

You can enable `xpack.security.enabled: true` with [following configuration](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L25):

```
esConfig: {}
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.security.enabled: true
```

Comment: Hi Mariusz, link is not working, is it possible to send again?

Comment: @yatta update the link, should work fine now